# Specify date to be added to db prior to load of data

Tags: java, sql, database

I am currently refactoring some old code that involves the insertion of data from array lists into a database table. 
 The old solution assume the date of entry for the data is today's date, which causes issues when loading older data. 
 Below is an example of this code.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
insert.setDate(1, sqlDate);

            while (iterUserName.hasNext() && iterFullName.hasNext(){
                insert.setString(2, iterUserName.next());
                insert.setString(3, iterFullName.next());
                insert.addBatch();
               }
```

Do you know how I can refactor the code so that when I am loading the data to the db I can specify the date dynamically? 
For instance if the array lists have information from a month ago I want to be able to insert that date as the report date as opposed to the current date. 
This method is executed via a bash script to load the data to the db if that is of any help.

Comment: Using `java.time.LocalDate` is preferred over `java.sql.Date` these days (and you also don't need a `SimpleDateFormat` to create an instance of `java.sql.Date`)

Comment: Code appears to be incomplete.  You are iterating over what appears to be two lists of names.  Where would you get the 'old' date value from?  Conceptually, you would just use the date in the record.  If there is no date, use the current date.

Comment: Do you know about [JDBC escape syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc1020262.html)?

Comment: @vsfDawg Basically the records do not contain any date values and are loaded in the morning everyday so there was no need to change the code previously. Now records from the past need to be loaded. There is no way to know from the records themselves what date they are from, hence I need to manually add the dates for multiple records. Also the current date will not be suitable as these records need to be accurate based on the date they were created.

Comment: @Abra I will take a look at this thanks for the recommendation!